# Raptor_udf2 exploit in MariaDB

Tags: c, mariadb

The system I am trying to crack has MySQL/MariaDB running as root. I have access to the login and am now trying to use the raptor_udf2 exploit to do some PrivacyEscalation.
[Github Link](https://github.com/1N3/PrivEsc/blob/master/mysql/raptor_udf.c)
I follow the instructions given to me within the code.
However when I reach the instruction

```
create function do_system returns integer soname 'raptor_udf2.so';
```

[image: Error Message]
I am not quite sure, what I am doing wrong, but if I am completely honest, I am not sure what I am doing in the first place, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Also I am not sure what to tag this as since neither pentesting nor privacy escalation exists as tags.

Answer (score 0):

show variables like '%plugin%';
changed the path